# trying to insert values into MYSQL from Java using JDBC statement getting an error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert some values into MYSQL from Java using the following JDBC statement:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO abc.example(name,email,salary) VALUES (?,?,?)";
mystmt = myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
System.out.println("enter name");
String name=scan.next();
System.out.println("enter email");
String email=scan.next();
System.out.println("enter salary");
int Salary=scan.nextInt();
mystmt.setString(1,name);
mystmt.setString(2,email);
mystmt.setInt(3,Salary);                
int i =mystmt.executeUpdate(sql);
System.out.println(i+"records inserted\n");
```

But I'm getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1372)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1385)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1752)
at jdbc1.Preaprex.main(Preaprex.java:36)
```

Comment: Show the code (add it to the question)

Comment: I added now....

Comment: Add more tags, so more people can find your question (here `MySQL`, `JDBC`).
I don't work much with Java, but most of the collections starts with index `0` not `1`.

Comment: @WebDucer: but not the index for parameters in JDBC. The code looks correct

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace and indicate the line that throws the exception

Comment: full stacktrace is posted, error is thown at line mystmt.setString(1,name).